# javascript console return Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm trying to show alert message before an action happens in js here is my code :

```
 content+='<a href='+delete_url+' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');\"><button class="w-11/12 text-xs text-center text-white mx-auto bg-purple-900 py-1 px-2 rounded-xl"><i class="far fa-images"></i></button></a>';
```

but it shows nothing , when i change to `'""'` it raise this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'

thank you in advance ..

Comment: You can already see from the syntax highlighting that your quotes are messed up. Use a template literal instead.

Comment: i need ajax request , thats why i used inside the js , yes the `return` highlighted

Comment: I think it will work if you delete the `return` keyword.

Comment: yes , but it always shows the alert message

Comment: Avoid the problem entirely; get rid of the outdated (and bad practice) `onclick` attribute and use unobtrusive event handlers instead.